# How to return a dataframe from sklearn TFIDF Vectorizer within pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf

**How can I get TFIDF Vectorizer to return a pandas dataframe with respective column names, inside an sklearn pipeline used for cross-validation?**

I have an Sklearn Pipeline, where one of the steps is a TFIDF Vectorizer:

```
class InspectPipeline(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, x):
        return x

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        self.df = x
        return self


pipeline = Pipeline(
        [
         ("selector", ItemSelector(key="text_column")),
         ("vectorizer", TfidfVectorizer()),
         ("debug", InspectPipeline()),
         ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier())
        ]
)
```

I have created the class `InspectPipeline` in order to later inspect what were the features passed to the classifier (by running `pipeline.best_estimator_.named_steps['debug'].df`). However, TfidfVectorizer returns a sparse matrix which is what I get when I do `pipeline.best_estimator_.named_steps['debug'].df` . Instead of getting a sparse matrix, I would like to get the TFIDF vector as a pandas dataframe, where the column names are the respective tfidf tokens.

I know that `tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()` could help know the column names. But how can I include this + transforming the sparse matrix to a dataframe, within the pipeline?

Comment: Is the dense version of the sparse matrix small enough to fit in memory?

Comment: Yes @swhat, I have enough memory to fit the dense version of the matrix. My problem is rather how can I make that transformation inside the pipeline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extend TfidfVectorizer to instead return a DataFrame with the desired column names, and use that in your pipeline.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

class DenseTfidfVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer):

    def transform(self, raw_documents, copy=True):
        X = super().transform(raw_documents, copy=copy)
        df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=self.get_feature_names())
        return df

    def fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y=None):
        X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents, y=y)
        df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=self.get_feature_names())
        return df
```

Comment: This works! Thanks @swhat! I also had to substitute `                            ("vectorizer", DenseTfidfVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer())` in my pipeline

Comment: Edit: have to use the following in pipeline: ("vectorizer", DenseTfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5))

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.get_feature_names), you could use the following approach to

a. directly access `.get_feature_names()` outside the pipeline and inspect the dataframe (with named columns) there

b. [apply `.fit_transform` on data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform) outside the pipeline

```
pipeline = Pipeline(....)

# a. extract .get_feature_names() to use as column names in the dataframe
feature_names = (
                pipeline.best_estimator_
                        .named_steps['vectorizer']
                        .get_feature_names()
                )    

# b. get the TFIDF vector
data2 = (
         pipeline.best_estimator_
                 .named_steps['vectorizer']
                 .fit_transform(raw_data)
        )

# put into a pandas dataframe
transformed = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=feature_names)
```

This way you could perhaps skip the `debug` step from the pipeline altogether and inspect the dataframe outside the pipeline.